# Send JSON from Javascript web app to Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I have a web app that creates a JSON. Also I have a python app that reads in JSON. Right now I am only able to use console.log to see the JSON. This functions returns my JSON:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var geojsonFeature = e.layer.toGeoJSON();
    console.log(geojsonFeature);
```

How can I send this JSON to my Python app. Is Flask a good option to do that?

[enter link description here](https://rawgithub.com/ustroetz/Harvest-Cost-Analysis-CSFS/master/visualization/index.html)

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking at this very popular question on using [jquery to serialise JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery) to then send to your server (so that flask can read it).

You can then use the jquery `$.ajax()` function ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) to POST your data.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://path.to.yourserver.com/",
data: "{your: data}"
})
```

There's also some documentation on using jquery for AJAX requests in the [flask documentation.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.post('//url.to.python.com', { 
               "key": "value", 
               "key2": "value2"
             }, function(data){
              //Your returned data on success
 }).fail(function() {
   console.log( "error" );
 });
```